# Default values for a dropdown when forms loads in odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I'd like to have a dropdown filtered based on another value of the form when the forms load,
I've been trying to do it in the default_get method, the fields receive the correct data but the dropdown seems not to update

```
@api.model
def default_get(self, fields_list):
    result = super(ProjectTask, self).default_get(fields_list)
    #some logic to get user list, pre filtered
    result['user_id'] = users_list
```

user_list contains the pre-filtered list of user ids

Edit

this list is populated like this:

```
 for e in result_list:
        users_list.append((0,0,{
            'user_id':e['user_id'].id
        }))
```

The relationship is many to one as follows:

```
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users',
    string='Assigned to',
    default=False,
    index=True, track_visibility='always')
```

I'm looking to load a domain based on the values in the form
I have exactly [this issue presented in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512746/odoo-dynamic-many2one-domain), I tried the answer proposed without any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I followed [this approach](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/odoo-10-how-to-compute-domain-dynamic-domain-set-a-domain-based-on-a-function-or-a-field-157682), the highlights of the solution:

- Defining a function to create a dynamic domain didn't work for me
- I create a computed field with the filtered information
- Set the domain in the view, not in the code
- Use a common function that set the values for a list
- Add the computed field to the view
- The same function set the values for the on change on the dropdown and the computed field

Check the following code:

```
fetched_users = fields.Many2many('res.users', compute='fetch_available_employees_default')

def fetch_available_employees_default(self):
    # custom logic, set the computed field and also return the list
    self.fetched_users = users_list      
    return users_list
```

the on change event of the dropdown, to re-populate the field

```
@api.onchange('role_id')
def fetch_available_employees(self):
    users_list = self.fetch_available_employees_default()
    if len(users_list)>0:
        return {'domain': {'user_id': [('id', 'in', users_list)] }}
    else:
        # return empy list by default
        return {'domain': {'user_id': [('id', '=', -1)]}}
```

In the View:

```
<field name="fetched_users" invisible="True"/>

<xpath expr="//field[@name='user_id']" position="attributes">
     <attribute name="domain">
         [('id','in',fetched_users)]
     </attribute>
 </xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we do dropdown from a many2one type of field, Odoo calls `name_search` and `name_get` method for that object (in this case `res.users`).

Override `name_search` method of `res.users` object and pass context value from xml side to get change on specific views. Otherwise it apply for global.

Comment: I just want that behavior in one form, I'm afraid if I override name_search will affect other parts

Comment: Yes. That's why you need to add context in that one form view. In a name_search method, check that context, if you found added context value, execute your custom logic otherwise execute Odoo core logic.

Comment: this is exactly the issue I'm having to give you more context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512746/odoo-dynamic-many2one-domain